# Webcam Supported for Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: drivers, usb, webcam

Which usb webcam is supported for ubuntu 14.04 32 bit.please suggest me for the same which will take snap through mplayer command and stored on system.

Comment: Your question is too broad and hardware recommendation is off topic on Ask Ubuntu. You can ask about the support of a specific device here or you can ask for a wider suggestion of supported devices over on [HardwareRecs.SE].

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how well-maintained this site is, but you can check out the list of [supported UVC devices here](http://www.ideasonboard.org/uvc/#devices). This site was referred by the [Ubuntu Community Help Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Webcam) on webcams.